# Bug in chrome after photo upload

Tags: php, jquery

Link http://invait.ru/CollectiveGift_template1.php

**Browser is Chrome**

I do the following:

1) Go on link http://invait.ru/CollectiveGift_template1.php

2) Choose an image

[image: step 2]

3) When showing an image for crop, i click on it without a crop area

[image: step3]

**And now my page scrolls down.**

**Tell me please how stop this bug in chrome?**

**Code JSCROP** [**HERE**](http://pastebin.com/npUVq4Ze)

P.S.: Firefox doesn't have this bug...

***P.P.S.: please if you want click on downvote tell mme answer. I think aboout this problem 2 days...***

Comment: Is this your website ? If so.. do you know which function is triggered when clicking ?

Comment: when click on image work `Jcrop.js` about this - https://github.com/tapmodo/Jcrop

Comment: when i click outside the crop area it fire this error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . jquery.Jcrop.css:11
hope this help

Comment: Doesn't seem to belong anywhere on stackexchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find this part of your code in your Jscrop.js:

```
  function watchKeys() //{{{
  {
    if (options.keySupport) {
      $keymgr.show();
      $keymgr.focus();
    }
  }
  //}}}
```

And remove this line:

```
      $keymgr.focus();
```

It is found on line 1238 in your file. Tell me if this fixes things.

This will remove the keys functionality.
Please take a look at this discussion: http://code.google.com/p/jcrop/issues/detail?id=39#c4
If you need the keys functionality, try changing fixed to absolute on line 1224:

```
var $keymgr = $('<input type="radio" />').css({
        position: 'fixed'
```

and roll back the previous change

Comment: You can't give any kind of meaningful answer to a meaningless question

Comment: @GordonM if you think that question is meaningless said me answer please

Comment: code jscrop [**here**](http://pastebin.com/npUVq4Ze)

Comment: Try the update - remove that line

Comment: @DreamWave Big thanks, worked))

Comment: There should be a problem now with the key events. There is another fix to this problem if you need that resolved too. Please take alook at this discussion: http://code.google.com/p/jcrop/issues/detail?id=39#c4